# Image won't Display

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have an image on my WPF form. It displays fine in the IDE but when I run it, its not there.  Nor is the tooltip.

I've tried both .png and .jpg.  Its marked as visible.

```
<Grid>
<Image x:Name="imgLogo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="301,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Logo.jpg" Stretch="None" ToolTip="Logo"/>
<Label x:Name="lblTitle" Content="Task Utility" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="22"/>
<Button x:Name="btnExit" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="33,517,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Background="#FFD9422A" Foreground="#FFF7F3F3" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="-2.202,0.456"/>
......
</Grid>
```

Any ideas?  All the other elements (buttons, data grids, labels etc) work fine.

Comment: You've been around for a while here. I'm surprised I'm even tempted to link the F.A.Q here...   Any code ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a /Resources/Logo.jpg file relative to the folder where the debug folder or compiled application resides?

For example if the app is located at: `C:\myapp\myapp.exe` then the image should be in `C:\myapp\Resources\Logo.jpg`